# getAllInternetHeadersAsync returns empty string for sent messages

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

When I try get internet headers for sent messages it returns empty string but it works for received messages.

emailjs-mime-parser - works correct. I've got asyncResult.value as "";

```
import parser from 'emailjs-mime-parser';

export const getHeaders = async (mail: Office.MessageRead) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mail.getAllInternetHeadersAsync((asyncResult) => {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        const response = parser(asyncResult.value);
        resolve(response);
      } else {
        reject(new Error(asyncResult.error.message));
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Expecting: getAllInternetHeadersAsync returns headers for sent messages.

Answer (score 0):

`PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` MAPI property is only present on the received messages, never on sent messages. The message is sent and the headers are added by the transport provider asynchronously as the message is transmitted after it was already moved to the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Could I find some "workaround" for this rule? I needs "References" from Internet headers. Maybe I could get it by some REST endpoint?

Comment: You will most likely have `PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1039001F"`) property set - take a look at a sent message with Outlook]Spy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy - I am its author) - click IMessage button to see all available MAPI properties.

Comment: I found a solution. I use `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync` with `<t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>` tag.

Comment: But that can potentially return a multi-Mb message with attachments et al. If you only need a single property, request that property alone: `<ItemShape>
<t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
<t:AdditionalProperties>
<t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyType="String" PropertyTag="0x1039"/>
</t:AdditionalProperties>
</ItemShape>`

Answer (score 0):

hi @Alex Nietsvietov you can get outlook mail Internet Headers using this simple js.

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(getCallback);

 function getCallback(asyncResult) {
 if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
     try {
        var Header = asyncResult.value.match(/x-preferred-fruit:.*/gim)[0].slice(19);
           console.log(Header)
     
     } catch (error) {
         console.log("Error getting preferences from header: Header not found" + error);
    
     }
 } else {
     console.log("Error getting preferences from header: " + 
     JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
 }}
```

and you can Check original Microsoft office Api [Internet Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/internet-headers)